# How do I change the original language of a product type?

Tags: 8, commerce, i18n-l10n

On a multilingual site with `commerce` project I've created a product type while having one language selected as default but now I want to switch it to a different one. On `/admin/commerce/config/product-types/producttypemachinename/edit/translate` I see what the current original language is oviously but I can't edit it on `/admin/commerce/config/product-types/producttypemachinename/edit`. Is it ok if I edit it in the database? Does anyone have some ready SQL statements or at least know where it's stored?

I think product type is a [Configuration Entity](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/entity-api/configuration-entity) and I'm now searching where these are stored in the [database](https://www.drupal.org/node/1785994).

I've found **something** in

```sql
SELECT * from `drupal_config` WHERE name LIKE "commerce_product.commerce_product_type%";
SELECT * from `drupal_key_value` WHERE collection="config.entity.key_store.commerce_product_type";
```

but the data columns there are `longblob`.

Update: with the next SQL I can confirm that original language is stored in the "config" table:

```sql
SELECT collection,name,CAST(data as CHAR) from `drupal_config` WHERE name LIKE "commerce_product.commerce_product_type%";
```

Update: even after [editing](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/297924/7177) the longblob value and setting langcode to `en` it's still not English original in the admin interface.

Update: just had to clear the cache, it's now changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I haven't found any easy way I had to edit it [in the database manually](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/297924/7177) and clear the cache after that.

#### Update:

It's easy with exporting at

`/admin/config/development/configuration/single/export`
and importing at

`/admin/config/development/configuration/single/import`